# Factorize $4a^2 - 9b^2 -2a - 3b$

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I found this question in my textbook - 
$$4a^2 - 9b^2 -2a - 3b$$
I am in ninth grade and we have been taught how to factorize using identities, splitting the middle term and by using identities. I tried combining the first 2 terms using the identity $a^2 - b^2 = (a+b)\cdot(a-b)$ but I couldn't factorize the while expression even then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were on the right track: $4a^2-9b^2=(2a)^2-(3b)^2=(2a-3b)(2a+3b)$, so

$$4a^2-9b^2-2a-3b=(2a-3b)(2a+3b)-(2a+3b)\;.$$

Can you finish it from there by pulling out a common factor?

Comment: So I would get $(2a+3b)(2a-3b-1)$ right ?

Comment: @Mayank: Yes, that’s right.